# Clustered and nonclustered indexes performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, clustered-index

I have a huge table (~ 10 million rows) with clustered PK on a random uniqueidentifier column. The most operations I do with this table is inserting a new row if there is not yet a row with the same pk. (To improve performance of it I use IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON option)

My question is

Can I get rid of clustered index at all on this table? I mean when I insert a row into a table with clustered index it should rearrange data physicaly. May be it is better to drop clustered index and create nonclustered index on that colum to avoid data rearrangement?

I can't do an experiment on the live db because if performance falls down it will be a headache. On the test db I can only see 'Clustered Index Insert 100%' in the case with clustered index and 'table insert' + some seeking opertations in the nonclustered index in the case with non-clustered index.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, a GUID as a clustered index isn't a very good choice, especially on a large table - see [Kim Tripp: GUID as a primary key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx). Try to use an `INT IDENTITY` as your clustering key - should make quite a difference! But don't get rid of your clustering key altogether - a heap is even slower...

Comment: agree with marc_s: you're going to see alot of page splits...

Comment: Did you actually did any measurement that showed that the clustered index is causing insert performance problems? If you're only guessing, I suggest you measure first, follow the Waits and Queues methodology: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GUIDs may seem to be a natural choice for your primary key - and if you really must, you could probably argue to use it for the PRIMARY KEY of the table. What I'd strongly recommend **not to do** is use the GUID column as the **clustering key**, which SQL Server does by default, unless you specifically tell it not to.

You really need to keep two issues apart:

1) the **primary key** is a logical construct - one of the candidate keys that uniquely and reliably identifies every row in your table. This can be anything, really - an INT, a GUID, a string - pick what makes most sense for your scenario.

2) the **clustering key** (the column or columns that define the "clustered index" on the table) - this is a *physical* storage-related thing, and here, a small, stable, ever-increasing data type is your best pick - `INT` or `BIGINT` as your default option.

By default, the primary key on a SQL Server table is also used as the clustering key - but that doesn't need to be that way! I've personally seen massive performance gains when breaking up the previous GUID-based Primary / Clustered Key into two separate key - the primary (logical) key on the `GUID`, and the clustering (ordering) key on a separate `INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column.

As [Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx) - the Queen of Indexing - and others have stated a great many times - a GUID as the clustering key isn't optimal, since due to its randomness, it will lead to massive page and index fragmentation and to generally bad performance.

Yes, I know - there's `newsequentialid()` in SQL Server 2005 and up - but even that is not truly and fully sequential and thus also suffers from the same problems as the GUID - just a bit less prominently so.

Then there's another issue to consider: the clustering key on a table will be added to each and every entry on each and every non-clustered index on your table as well - thus you really want to make sure it's as small as possible. Typically, an INT with 2+ billion rows should be sufficient for the vast majority of tables - and compared to a GUID as the clustering key, you can save yourself hundreds of megabytes of storage on disk and in server memory.

Quick calculation - using INT vs. GUID as Primary and Clustering Key:

- Base Table with 1'000'000 rows (3.8 MB vs. 15.26 MB)
- 6 nonclustered indexes (22.89 MB vs. 91.55 MB)

**TOTAL: 25 MB vs. 106 MB** - and that's just on a single table!

Some more food for thought - excellent stuff by Kimberly Tripp - read it, read it again, digest it! It's the SQL Server indexing gospel, really. As she shows in her "The Clustered Index Debate contiues", having a **good clustering key** (as opposed to none or a bad one) really does speed up pretty much all database operations! It's a good idea - but it has to be a good clustering key....

- [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEY and/or clustered key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)
- [The clustered index debate continues](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx)
- [Ever-increasing clustering key - the Clustered Index Debate..........again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx)
- [Disk space is cheap - that's **not** the point!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Disk-space-is-cheap.aspx)

Marc

Comment: Thanks Mark for very explicit explanations! I need some time to think about it and then I'll write about the results.

Comment: Can we use a datetime column as a new clustered key? In that table there is a column 'CreatedDate' and we need to get max(CreatedDate) sometimes. It is sequential and never changes.

Comment: @Ruslan: you can - but you shouldn't - at least not alone. A DateTime isn't guaranteed to be uniqe - and if it's not, SQL Server will add 4 bytes to each entry... not recommended.... `INT IDENTITY` really is the best choice - possibly together with a DateTime (but I wouldn't put the DateTime column into the clustering key myself)